# Trying to run MASM code for a few different operations to run, but Keep getting the error A2074 cannot access label through segment register

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

This is my assignment:

> make sure you installed MASM correctly and that you can run/debug your simple assembly language.
>
> Run the following calculations using MASM and assign the result to the same or different registers. Share a screenshot showing the content of the register.
>
> B- Use memory locations with different sizes: byte, word, double word, quad word, save the calculated values in the memory locations. Take a screen shot with of the memory using at least two different sizes for the same values and submit in the same word document.
>
> - 4 + 5 * 2
> - 12 −1
> - −5 + 2
> - (4 + 2) * 6
> - 16 / 5
> - − ( 3 + 4 ) * ( 6 − 1 ) − 35
> - − 3 + 4 * 6 − 1
> - 25 MOD 3
>
> Submit a copy of your code and a screenshot of the registers after
> each operation, or if you saved the result in different registers,
> just use one screenshot, and screenshots for the memory with at least
> two different data size.

This is the MASM code:

```
; Declare data segment
DATA SEGMENT
    num1 DW 4
    num2 DW 5
    num3 DW 2
    num4 DW 1
    num5 DW -5
    num6 DW 2
    num7 DW 6
    num8 DW 3
    num9 DW 4
    num10 DW 16
    num11 DW 5
    num12 DW 3
    num13 DW 6
    num14 DW 1
    num15 DW 35
DATA ENDS

; Declare code segment
CODE SEGMENT
MAIN PROC

; Calculate 4 + 5 * 2 and store in num4
mov ax, num1
add ax, num2
mov bx, num3
mul bx
mov num4, ax

; Calculate 12 - 1 and store in num11
mov ax, num10
sub ax, num11
mov num11, ax

; Calculate -5 + 2 and store in num6
mov ax, num5
add ax, num6
mov num6, ax

; Calculate (4 + 2) * 6 and store in num7
mov ax, num1
add ax, num3
mov bx, num7
mul bx
mov num7, ax

; Calculate 16 / 5 and store in num11
mov ax, num10
cwd
mov bx, num11
div bx
mov num11, ax

; Calculate -(3 + 4) * (6 - 1) - 35 and store in num14
mov ax, num12
add ax, num9
neg ax
mov bx, num13
sub bx, num14
mul bx
sub ax, num15
mov num14, ax

; Calculate -3 + 4 * 6 - 1 and store in num6
mov ax, num5
neg ax
mov bx, num3
mul bx
add ax, num1
sub ax, num14
mov num6, ax

; Calculate 25 MOD 3 and store in num9
mov ax, num8
mov bx, num11
cwd
div bx
mov ax, num8
mov bx, num11
mul bx
sub ax, num8
mov num9, ax

; Exit program
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

MAIN ENDP
CODE ENDS
END MAIN
```

And this are the errors I get when I run this in cmd:

> Assembling: LabW6.asm
> LabW6.asm(25) : error A2074:cannot access label through segment registers
> LabW6.asm(26) : error A2074:cannot access label through segment registers
> LabW6.asm(27) : error A2074:cannot access label through segment registers
> LabW6.asm(29) : error A2074:cannot access label through segment registers
> LabW6.asm(32) : error A2074:cannot access label through segment registers
> LabW6.asm(33) : error A2074:cannot access label through segment registers
> .....
> *(and a great many more of this same error, with different line numbers)*
> .......
> LabW6.asm(91) : warning A4023:with /coff switch, leading underscore required for start address :

Comment: The code you are showing is for MSDOS (not Windows). For this to build a DOS EXE program you'd have to add `ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA` after `CODE SEGMENT` to set the assumed segments. This is needed if you don't use the simplified DOS segments and define your own. I mention Windows because the error `warning A4023:with /coff switch,` suggests to me that the commands you are using are attempting to build a windows executable. WWhat command(s) are you using to compile and link? Are you intending to write DOS EXE or Windows EXEs?

Comment: 64-bit quad word variables (as required by your assignment) are a lot easier to use in 64-bit code than in 16-bit.  In 16 or 32-bit mode, the widest register size you can use is 32-bit, so you'd need to handle things in two halves.  (Using qword for a dividend or product is easy, though, if the quotient or multiplicands are small.  x86 has narrowing division and widening multiply, so you don't actually need to do any extended-precision stuff.)